# impossible to convert a date more than three weeks with momentjs

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to use the plugin js calendarfull initialized and I would like the calendar.
and then stored in the db.

as I receive a date in FR, at first I call into IN with momentjs like this:

```
moment(new Date("01/05/2015")).format("YYYY-DD-MM")
```

`it returns me well : 2015-01-05`

Now if I try to change this date : `30/05/2015`
to put it in EN told me the date is invalid
by cons if I use : `11/05/2015`

he converted me well the date in `EN`

I feel that we are limited in the conversion of the dates from the time lag of the current date, since it is impossible to convert the date Date `2015-01-06`ditla me it is invalid .

there would have a way to automatically convert the date momentsjs even a date more than 3 months?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no limit. It looks like it is expecting the format to be 'MM/DD/YYYY'. Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the moment instance from a string without specifying the format. It will behave [differently on each browser](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Instead, use the String + Format constructor:

```
moment("01/05/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-DD-MM");
// => '2015-01-05'
moment("30/05/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-DD-MM");
// => '2015-30-05'
```

From moment.js [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because
>   there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what
>   works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings,
>   you should use String + Format.